# How to create an object in Node js backend server and pass it to Angular 2 front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular2-services

I want to form an javascript object at node server and 
example : 
below is the object present in my server.js file

```
chart = {property: value, property: value, property: value}
```

I want to fetch same object in angular 2 service which is injected to a component.

Please suggest how can I achieve the same?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for in your question. Is your Node backend a REST API? If so, you'll want to use Angular's HttpClient to make a rest api call to it to get the data you want.

Comment: can you please add sample code for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Httpclient of angular. Here is an example:

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  register(username: string, randomPass: string, email: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/register',
      {username: username, randomPass: randomPass, email: email})
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
}
```

In our service we injected the HttpClient which is an abstraction layer over AJAX which Angular provides for us. This service makes a post request with the following code `this.http.post`. This function takes two arguments, the URL to which the `POST` request is sent, and the keyvalue pairs in the body of the `POST` request. The function returns an Observable which can be subscribed to in the component which uses this function.

**Register component (only register function):**

```
 public register(username: string, randomPass: string, email: string) {
      this.registerService.register(username, email)
        .subscribe(myResponse => {
          if (myResponse.success) {
            this.registered = true;
        });
    }
  }
```

This function should be called when we want to make the AJAX request. It uses [dependency inversion principle](https://netbasal.com/demystifying-the-dependency-inversion-principle-in-angular-a2daca9b05ee), this way we can alter the service without having to alter the component drastically.

**NodeJS express Backend**

I suppose you already have a basic express app running then this is the middleware you need to listen to the AJAX call and respond with the object which you want to send.

```
app.post('register', (req, res, next) => {
   chart = {property: value, property: value, property: value}

   return res.json(chart);
});
```

This middleware (part of express framework) listens to `POST` requests on the register component. It then sends a `JSON` response with the values of the chart object.

If anything is not clear I strongly suggest that you try to grasp the principle of read some articles about the topic.